# Magnolia 5.5.5 - Open dialog in new window

Tags: magnolia

I want to open all component-dialogs in a new windows or tabs. Is that possible and if yes, how can I do this?

I was thinking of modifying the edit handler of the component. How and where would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**
Depending on what you want to do, it might not make sense, but, you could start here:

```
info.magnolia.ui.contentapp.detail.action.EditItemActionDefinition
info.magnolia.ui.dialog.formdialog.FormDialogPresenterImpl
```

maybe even https://www.magnolia-cms.com/blogs/boris-kraft/detail~&headless-or-full-bodied-cms--magnolia-provides-all-the-solutions~.html

**Longer answer:**
It depends on what you are trying to do - we can get to any state in Magnolia by re-using location fragments like this one: `#app:contacts:detail;/ldavinci:edit`
That tells me we are in edit mode on a particular path (from root of some workspace) in the detail subapp of the contacts app.  What that means in this case is, we've opened a dialog in a tab.
Likewise: `#app:contacts:browser;/ldavinci:treeview:` represents another state.

So we can programmatically move to new locations if we know the parts of those location fragments.  But these are locations (app,subapp,path) *within* Magnolia, not within a web browser.

A browser tab is not the same thing as a Magnolia tab; the latter represents a tab within a Magnolia form, and hasn't anything to do with a web browser - so it would not open.

Even if we did hijack that action, what you'll get in this case is the whole Magnolia rig, *not* just the dialog, standalone, in a new browser tab or window, which is not what I suspect you are interested in.  If you are interested in the dialog, by itself, independent of the rest of the Magnolia UI, you might have to start looking at

```
info.magnolia.ui.dialog.formdialog.FormDialogPresenterImpl
146     public DialogView start(..
which calls
165     private void buildView(..
and sets up overlays, etc.
(sepcifically through 167         formPresenter.presentView(..)
...
```

so then if we look in here:

```
info.magnolia.ui.dialog.formdialog.FormPresenterImpl:
123         buildForm((FormView) this.formView, formDefinition, item, parent, activeLocale);
```

which eventually calls this guy

```
198     private void buildReducedForm(..
```

and it adds it to existing FormViewReduced (`info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.form.FormViewReduced`) with a certain modality.

FVR is implemented by

```
info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.form.Form
```

which is what should actually display the form.

and the form gets displayed on a

```
info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.tabsheet.MagnoliaTabSheet
```

So in `info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.gwt.client.tabsheet.widget.MagnoliaTabSheetViewImpl:`
...etc. and further on down the rabbit hole, and what would this stuff mean outside the context of Magnolia anyway?

I guess you could also look here:

```
info.magnolia.ui.contentapp.detail.action.EditItemActionDefinition
```

You can edit these data over our REST API anyway, so maybe you're trying to move the dialogs out of Magnolia to accomplish something along that line?